# Computing mean of different columns depending on date

Tags: r, date, mean

My data set is about forest fires and NDVI values (a value ranging from 0 to 1, indicating how green is the surface). It has an initial column which says when the forest fire of row one took place, and subsequent columns indicating the NDVI value on different dates, before and after the fire happened. NDVI values before the fire are substantially higher compared with values after the fire. Something like:

```
data1989 <- data.frame("date_fire" = c("1987-01-01", "1987-07-03", "1988-01-01"), 
                       "1986-01-01" = c(0.5, 0.589, 0.66), 
                       "1986-06-03" = c(0.56, 0.447, 0.75), 
                       "1986-10-19" = c(0.8, NA, 0.83),
                       "1987-01-19" = c(0.75, 0.65,0.75), 
                       "1987-06-19" = c(0.1, 0.55,0.811),
                       "1987-10-19" = c(0.15, 0.12, 0.780),
                       "1988-01-19" = c(0.2, 0.22,0.32), 
                       "1988-06-19" = c(0.18, 0.21,0.23),
                       "1988-10-19" = c(0.21, 0.24, 0.250),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
> data1989
   date_fire X1986.01.01 X1986.06.03 X1986.10.19 X1987.01.19 X1987.06.19 X1987.10.19 X1988.01.19 X1988.06.19 X1988.10.19
1 1987-01-01       0.500       0.560        0.80        0.75       0.100        0.15        0.20        0.18        0.21
2 1987-07-03       0.589       0.447          NA        0.65       0.550        0.12        0.22        0.21        0.24
3 1988-01-01       0.660       0.750        0.83        0.75       0.811        0.78        0.32        0.23        0.25
```

I would like to compute the average of NDVI values, in a new column, PRIOR to the forest fire. In case one, it would be the average of columns 2, 3, 4 and 5.

What I need to get is:

```
date_fire    X1986.01.01 X1986.06.03 X1986.10.19 X1987.01.19 X1987.06.19 X1987.10.19 X1988.01.19 X1988.06.19 X1988.10.19 meanPreFire
1 1987-01-01       0.500       0.560        0.80        0.75       0.100        0.15        0.20        0.18        0.21       0.653
2 1987-07-03       0.589       0.447          NA        0.65       0.550        0.12        0.22        0.21        0.24       0.559
3 1988-01-01       0.660       0.750        0.83        0.75       0.811        0.78        0.32        0.23        0.25       0.764
```

Thanks!

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

How to adapt the code with more than one column to exclude:

```
   data1989 <- data.frame("date_fire" = c("1987-02-01", "1987-07-03", "1988-01-01"), 
                       "type" = c("oak", "pine", "oak"),
                       "meanRainfall" = c(600, 300, 450),
                       "1986.01.01" = c(0.5, 0.589, 0.66), 
                       "1986.06.03" = c(0.56, 0.447, 0.75), 
                       "1986.10.19" = c(0.8, NA, 0.83),
                       "1987.01.19" = c(0.75, 0.65,0.75), 
                       "1987.06.19" = c(0.1, 0.55,0.811),
                       "1987.10.19" = c(0.15, 0.12, 0.780),
                       "1988.01.19" = c(0.2, 0.22,0.32), 
                       "1988.06.19" = c(0.18, 0.21,0.23),
                       "1988.10.19" = c(0.21, 0.24, 0.250),
                       check.names = FALSE,
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Using:

```
j1 <- findInterval(as.Date(data1989$date_fire), as.Date(names(data1989)[-(1:3)],format="%Y.%m.%d"))
m1 <- cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(data1989)), j1), sequence(j1))
data1989$meanPreFire <- tapply(data1989[-(1:3)][m1], m1[,1], FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)

> data1989
   date_fire type meanRainfall 1986.01.01 1986.06.03 1986.10.19 1987.01.19 1987.06.19 1987.10.19 1988.01.19 1988.06.19 1988.10.19 meanPreFire
1 1987-02-01  oak          600      0.500      0.560       0.80       0.75      0.100       0.15       0.20       0.18       0.21      0.6525
2 1987-07-03 pine          300      0.589      0.447         NA       0.65      0.550       0.12       0.22       0.21       0.24      0.5590
3 1988-01-01  oak          450      0.660      0.750       0.83       0.75      0.811       0.78       0.32       0.23       0.25      0.7635
```

Comment: Your edit is not giving any error/warning for me

Comment: Nono Akrun, it works perfectly! But when I use an adaptation of this code to my real dataset it produces the error! But indeed, not in this piece of code!

Comment: it could be that the dates names or the 'data_fire' Dates are not sorted in the actual dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reshape data to the long form and filter dates prior to the forest fire.

```
library(tidyverse)

data1989 %>%
  pivot_longer(-date_fire, names_to = "date") %>%
  mutate(date_fire = as.Date(date_fire),
         date = as.Date(date, "X%Y.%m.%d")) %>%
  filter(date < date_fire) %>%
  group_by(date_fire) %>%
  summarise(meanPreFire = mean(value, na.rm = T))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   date_fire  meanPreFire
#   <date>           <dbl>
# 1 1987-01-01       0.62 
# 2 1987-07-03       0.559
# 3 1988-01-01       0.764
```

Comment: Hi Darren! I finally decided to reshape all my data. I am getting used to tydyverse! In the line  `pivot_longer(-date_fire, names_to = "date")`, you are asking to exclude `date_fire`from the reshaping. How can I do to exclude not only this column but also the column "type"? (Check my edit to original post  for that las thing) Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I tried `data1989 %>%
  pivot_longer(c(-date_fire,-type), names_to = "date") %>%
  mutate(date_fire = as.Date(date_fire), date = as.Date(date, "X%Y.%m.%d")) %>%
  filter(date < date_fire) %>%
  group_by(date_fire,type) %>%
  summarise(meanPreFire = mean(value, na.rm = T))` but no results so far...

Comment: got it: `-c(date_fire,type)`. I put your answer as the best answer because I think is the best approach!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R`, by creating a row/column index.  The column index can be got from `findInterval` with the column names and the 'date_fire'

```
j1 <- findInterval(as.Date(data1989$date_fire), as.Date(names(data1989)[-1]))
l1 <- lapply(j1+1, `:`, ncol(data1989)-1)   
m1 <- cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(data1989)), j1), sequence(j1))
m2 <- cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(data1989)), lengths(l1)), unlist(l1))
data1989$meanPreFire <- tapply(data1989[-1][m1], m1[,1], FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
data1989$meanPostFire <- tapply(data1989[-1][m2], m2[,1], FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)


data1989
#   date_fire 1986-01-01 1986-06-03 1986-10-19 1987-01-19 1987-06-19 1987-10-19 1988-01-19 1988-06-19 1988-10-19
#1 1987-01-01      0.500      0.560       0.80       0.75      0.100       0.15       0.20       0.18       0.21
#2 1987-07-03      0.589      0.447         NA       0.65      0.550       0.12       0.22       0.21       0.24
#3 1988-01-01      0.660      0.750       0.83       0.75      0.811       0.78       0.32       0.23       0.25
#  meanPreFire meanPostFire
#1      0.6200    0.2650000
#2      0.5590    0.1975000
#3      0.7635    0.2666667
```

---

Or using `melt/dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(data1989), id.var = 'date_fire')[, 
    .(value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)), 
    .(date_fire, grp = c('postFire', 'preFire')[1 + (as.IDate(variable) < as.IDate(date_fire))]) ], date_fire ~ grp)[data1989, on = .(date_fire)]
#    date_fire  postFire preFire 1986-01-01 1986-06-03 1986-10-19 1987-01-19 1987-06-19 1987-10-19 1988-01-19 1988-06-19
#1: 1987-01-01 0.2650000  0.6200      0.500      0.560       0.80       0.75      0.100       0.15       0.20       0.18
#2: 1987-07-03 0.1975000  0.5590      0.589      0.447         NA       0.65      0.550       0.12       0.22       0.21
#3: 1988-01-01 0.2666667  0.7635      0.660      0.750       0.83       0.75      0.811       0.78       0.32       0.23
#   1988-10-19
#1:       0.21
#2:       0.24
#3:       0.25
```

#### data

```
data1989 <- data.frame("date_fire" = c("1987-01-01", "1987-07-03", "1988-01-01"), 
                       "1986-01-01" = c(0.5, 0.589, 0.66), 
                       "1986-06-03" = c(0.56, 0.447, 0.75), 
                       "1986-10-19" = c(0.8, NA, 0.83),
                       "1987-01-19" = c(0.75, 0.65,0.75), 
                       "1987-06-19" = c(0.1, 0.55,0.811),
                       "1987-10-19" = c(0.15, 0.12, 0.780),
                       "1988-01-19" = c(0.2, 0.22,0.32), 
                       "1988-06-19" = c(0.18, 0.21,0.23),
                       "1988-10-19" = c(0.21, 0.24, 0.250), check.names = FALSE,
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Akrun! That works super fine. In the case I have several columns to exclude, not just the first one, how would you adapt the script? I made an edit adding an example of that. Instead of `names(data1989)[-1]` I tried `names(data1989)[-(1:3)]` but doesn't work

Comment: @OriolBaenaCrespo `names` argument should work, `names(mtcars)[-(1:3)]#
[1] "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"`, but I think it is the other index `ncol(data1989)-1` that may need. some changes

Comment: Yes, got it working. Now I have other problems with my "real" dataset like `  'vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly and not contain NAs`. I'll keep working! Thanks again!

Comment: @OriolBaenaCrespo that would be the issue from `findInterval` as it requires sorted vector

Comment: Yes, but it works fine with the simple dataset you adapted (check my EDIT), but not in my real dataset. Though if I erase `check.names = FALSE`I have the same error. So in the case of my real dataset it has to do with names of the columns, I am not sure at all..

Comment: @OriolBaenaCrespo Do you have the same issue wiith `data.table` solution as it should be more general

Comment: Actually I didn't try it because I keep having this error: `Error in melt.data.table(setDT(data1989), id.var = "date_fire") : 
  One or more values in 'id.vars' is invalid.`

Comment: @OriolBaenaCrespo in that case, you need `id.var = c('data_fire', 'type', 'meanRainfall')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209636/discussion-between-oriol-baena-crespo-and-akrun).

Answer (score 2):

The solution would be much more concise if we would keep the data in long(er) form... but this reproduces the desired output:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data1989 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-date_fire, names_to = "date_NDVI", values_to = "value", names_prefix = "^X") %>% 
  mutate(date_fire = as.Date(date_fire, "%Y-%m-%d"),
         date_NDVI = as.Date(date_NDVI, "%Y.%m.%d")) %>% 
  group_by(date_fire) %>% 
  mutate(period = ifelse(date_NDVI < date_fire, "before_fire", "after_fire")) %>% 
  group_by(date_fire, period) %>% 
  mutate(average_NDVI = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = date_NDVI,  names_prefix = "X", values_from = value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = period, values_from = average_NDVI) %>% 
  group_by(date_fire) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(sum(., na.rm=T)))
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 12
  date_fire  `X1986-01-01` `X1986-06-03` `X1986-10-19` `X1987-01-19` `X1987-06-19` `X1987-10-19` `X1988-01-19` `X1988-06-19` `X1988-10-19` before_fire after_fire
  <date>             <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 1987-01-01         0.5           0.56           0.8           0.75         0.1            0.15          0.2           0.18          0.21       0.62       0.265
2 1987-07-03         0.589         0.447          0             0.65         0.55           0.12          0.22          0.21          0.24       0.559      0.198
3 1988-01-01         0.66          0.75           0.83          0.75         0.811          0.78          0.32          0.23          0.25       0.764      0.267
```

## Edit:

If we stop the expression right after calculating the averages we can use the data in this structure to easily calculate the variance or account for variable number of observations. I think it's ok to keep the `date_fire`as its own column, but I'd suggest leaving the other dates as a column (because they correspond to observations). Especially if we want to do more analysis with the data using `ggplot2` and other `tidyverse` functions.